# Why does Git fetch remember and use deleted local tracking branches

Tags: git, fetch, git-checkout, git-remote

Can you tell me why git seems to remember and use its “fetch memory” for a deleted local repository? I delete a local branch that was tracking a remote, and when that remote is completely rebuilt with new code and merges and I check it out and track it locally, I’m getting the original local/remote code (without updates/changes) if I don’t fetch first. Why does this happen? Why does git checkout the original outdated branch version even after the local branch was deleted? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to run `git fetch --prune some-remote` so that those references are removed from _your_ repo. I think it is related to the fact that you _own_ your repo..... so, if a remote branch is removed, they will be removed from _my_ repo when **I** want.

Comment: The fact that you are using _old_ information for a remote branch is not something to be surprised if you do _not_ fetch given that repos are **completely** separate entities.... the _syncing_ mechanism is `git fetch`so that you can get the updated info from remote repos.

Comment: By default, `git checkout foo` creates `foo` from `origin/foo` if `foo` does not exist yet. After you rebuild `foo` in the remote repository and before you run `git fetch` in the local repository, `origin/foo` still points at the outdated commit. So, the newly created `foo` still points at the old commit.

Comment: I very much appreciate the comments others have shared. I guess I feel that it is a.very non-intuitive “feature” for git to hang on to and reuse cached information for a remote.branch after the locally tracking branch has been deleted. Thanks so much again for taking the time to help me.